# What does John Bennett mean with "All those rich black people can't be wrong"?

Tags: ted

In Ted, around 22:22 John Bennett says that "All those rich black people can't be wrong". What did he mean by that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the full context:

> **WAITER:** Here is your dessert and champagne.
>
> **LORI:** Ooh, ***Cristal.***
>
> **JOHN:** It’s a special night. We’ve been dating for four years. And hey, all those rich black people can’t be wrong, right?

Champagne in general, and [Cristal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristal_%28wine%29) in particular, has long been perceived as a popular drink among hip-hop artists, whether for recereational use or as a symbol of wealth in various rap lyrics. You can read more about this in [this article](http://firstwefeast.com/drink/hip-hop-champagne-history/) as well as [this one](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/5056744.stm) from BBC News. Here's a clip from the latter:

> Rappers love it, quaff it, idolise it. But the makers of Cristal champagne have revealed they are at best ambivalent about the patronage of the hip-hop fraternity. [...] it is the drink of people whose taste in luxury items stretches only to things that are big and shiny, with big, shiny badges on them. Rappers like Gucci, they like Prada, they drive Bentleys and Benzes and most of all they sup Cristal.

Comment: The end of that quote should be "sip Cristal" shouldn't it?

Comment: Nah, it's just fancy Brit for sip. ;) (See [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sup#Verb).)

Comment: I'm British and I have never heard anyone use "sup" instead of sip. We use it as a verb: "to sup: to dine or eat supper"